# Ranorex: Force the video to be created

Tags: ranorex

From time to time there are errors that cause the termination of a test run. So that such test runs do not run forever and thus prevent the execution of further test runs, I limit the runtime of the corresponding scheduled task. In the Ranorex report, the last entry then is 'The test run has been aborted by the user' and a video shot up to that point is not saved.

But especially for debugging such errors the video analysis would be very useful. So how can I force the video to be saved despite the test run being aborted?